# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java

i meet with some exception problems while i'm coding to get the minimum spanning tree.

the error message is like :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Assignment.RandomGraph.main(RandomGraph.java:36)

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomGraph
{
public static Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
static int w [][];//it represents the weight between every two nodes.
static int n;//number of the vertices that you typed.
static int i, j;
static int visited[] = new int[n];
static int next[] = new int[n];
static int d[]=new int[n];



public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Find the shortest edge");
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of the vertices: ");
    n = br.nextInt();
    w = new int[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i!=j))
            {
            w[i][j] = w[j][i]= 1+(int)(Math.random()*9);
            }
            else if(i == j)
            {
                w[i][j] = w[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        next[i]=visited[i]=0;
        d[i]=32767;
    }
    Graph();
    Prim();
}

static void Graph()
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("  "+w[i][j]+"  ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}

static void Prim()
{
    int current=1;
    int total=1;
    int mincost;

    d[current]=0;
    visited[current]=1;
    do{
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if((w[current][i]!=0)&&(visited[i]==0)&&(w[current][i]<d[i]))
            {
                d[i]=w[current][i];
                next[i]=current;
            }
        }
        mincost = 32767;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if((visited[i]==0)&&d[i]<mincost)
            {
                mincost=d[i];
                current=i;
            }
        }
        visited[current]=1;
        total++;
    }while(total!=n);

    mincost=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        mincost=mincost+d[i];
        System.out.print("\n Minimum cost = "+mincost);
        System.out.print("\n Minimum Spanning tree is ");
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("\n"+i+" to "+next[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Debug it, this is the lesson you need to learn anyway.

Comment: ehhh... sorry...actually ..i dont know how to use it ...and im not familiar with java ..

Comment: The exception says that on line 36 of your file, you are trying to access an array like `array[i]` where `i` is invalid (i.e. not a valid index for that array) ==> Find the line and try to understand how that can happen.

Comment: You don't seem to understand variable scope / assignment or what the difference between static and local variables are.

Answer (score 2):

well the variable i in your fors should go from 0 to n, EXCLUSIVELY

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

if you declare an array / matrix as array[n], the system will create an array of size n but starting from 0, not 1

as in, `array[0] = first element NOT array[1]`

=> last element = `array[n-1]`

Comment: Wat? This isn't the problem. All of his loops are correct.

Comment: yes...i used your for loop...but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

because size of your next[] array is 0 and you try get elemeti with index 1.

read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: how could it be...i define the next as static int next[] = new int[n];

Comment: and the number of n is input by me...

Comment: No, it isn't. The allocation happens before you enter n

Comment: Ingo have right. Read this document I given you and check your code again

Comment: Can I declare these variables under local method to solve this problem?

Comment: of course you can. Do you know the reason of the error?

Comment: because the default value of int (primitive Integer) is 0. You declare and initializ your array as global variable so the JVM allocate memory for this arrya before the constructor is call so before you type 'n'. And also this array is static so is created even earlier (When program is starting). So size of this array is 0.

ps. in future don't use an array if you don't really need
ps2. in future don't use a static statment if you don't really need

Answer (score 0):

You have the arrays: `w [][], visited[], next[], d[]`. All have `n` elements. You can access them using indexes from `0 - (n-1)`.

The loop below in the main method (last one) and all the loops inside `static void Prim()` will throw an error because you have `i <= n`. You are trying to access `n index` which does not exist

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    next[i]=visited[i]=0;
    d[i]=32767;
}
```

Comment: i increased the n to n+1, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Shenjiayu don't increase the n. I said above that you can only use 0 - (n-1). **Decrease** it. Make all loops `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`